# How can I suppress specific Checkstyle rules in Eclipse?

Tags: checkstyle, suppression

I'm trying to use suppression filter but an unexpected error occurs.

Following is an error message.

"cannot initialize module
SuppressionFilter - Cannot set property 'file' in module SuppressionFilter to
'checkstyle-suppressions.xml': unable to find checkstyle-suppressions.xml - Document root element "suppressions", must match DOCTYPE root "module"."

Could you let me know how can I resolve this error?

Followings are a configuration file and a suppression file contents which I used.
I configured the suppression filter through eclipse menu(windows > preferences > checkstyle > configure > known modules Filter > Suppression Filter > add)

======================================

## configuration file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="MagicNumber">
            <property name="ignoreNumbers" value="-1, 0, 1"/>
        </module>
    </module>
</module>
```

===================================

## suppression filter file is ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">         

<suppressions>
    <suppress checks="MagicNumberCheck"
              files="Home.java"
              lines="350-370"/>
</suppressions>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your suppression filter file uses the 1.1 syntax, but claims to be using the newer 1.3 syntax. Exchange the header like so:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">
```

Also, your configuration file must reference the suppression filter. Add a module definition like this (add it before the last closing `</module>` tag, *not* under `Treewalker`):

```xml
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="${workspace_loc}/MyProject/suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
```

Using the `${workspace_loc}` variable makes sure that this works even when you copy or rename the workspace.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. Both configuration and suppression filter is working well.

Comment: Thanks!
Here's official documentation about that: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html
And example file - http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/files/suppressions_none.xml